# QGridLayout strange widget placement

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to build a simple GUI with PyQt5, where I have a few widgets which I want to align using `QGridLayout`.

Look at the following example code which I found on some website:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication)

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        title = QLabel('Title')
        author = QLabel('Author')
        review = QLabel('Review')

        titleEdit = QLineEdit()
        authorEdit = QLineEdit()
        reviewEdit = QTextEdit()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(title, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(titleEdit, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(author, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(authorEdit, 2, 1)

        grid.addWidget(review, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)


        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output

[image]

As you can see, there are three labels in the first column, each spanning one cell vertically and one cell horizontally.
In the second column there are two 1x1 widgets and one 5x1 widget.

Let's say I want to place another label called `test` and a lineedit called `testEdit` below.

Naively I would modify `initUI()` like this:

```
def initUI(self):

    title = QLabel('Title')
    author = QLabel('Author')
    review = QLabel('Review')
    test = QLabel('Test')

    titleEdit = QLineEdit()
    authorEdit = QLineEdit()
    reviewEdit = QTextEdit()
    testEdit = QTextEdit()

    grid = QGridLayout()
    grid.setSpacing(10)

    grid.addWidget(title, 1, 0)
    grid.addWidget(titleEdit, 1, 1)

    grid.addWidget(author, 2, 0)
    grid.addWidget(authorEdit, 2, 1)

    grid.addWidget(review, 3, 0)
    grid.addWidget(reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)

    grid.addWidget(test, 8, 0)
    grid.addWidget(testEdit, 8, 1)

    self.setLayout(grid)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle('Review')
    self.show()
```

Where I just placed the new 1x1 widgets in the 8th row, below the previous one, which produces:

Output 2

[image]

However the result is not what I would expect, since the testEdit-widget is definitely not of size 1x1 and the reviewEdit-widget is also altered.
So why doesn't it work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,
                             QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication,
                             )

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        title  = QLabel('Title')
        author = QLabel('Author')
        review = QLabel('Review')
        test   = QLabel('Test')            

        titleEdit  = QLineEdit()
        authorEdit = QLineEdit()
        reviewEdit = QTextEdit()
        testEdit   = QTextEdit()                 
        testEdit.setMaximumHeight(20)         # +++

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(title,      1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(titleEdit,  1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(author,     2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(authorEdit, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(review,     3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)   

        grid.addWidget(test,       8, 0)               
        grid.addWidget(testEdit,   8, 1)      

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this is not what I want to achieve. I want `testEdit` to be of the same size as `titleEdit`or `authorEdit`, not as `reviewEdit`.
And how did you come up with 22?

Comment: Thank you, now it works. Could you maybe elaborate on why the height is changed in the first place? So why does `testEdit` have different default values than e.g. `titleEdit`?

Comment: `testEdit` inherited `QTextEdit()`. 
`titleEdit` inherited  `QLineEdit()`.

Comment: Ok, I guess I got it now. At first I thought the cell dimensions were fixed and cells are just grouped together for larger widgets, but that seems not to be the case. Thank you again.